# Angular2 Like request MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, angular

I want to do a pretty simple thing, a function that does a query to mongoDB using a Like. But I don't seem to make it works.

At the moment it looks like this :

```
searchChannel(valueToSearch:string){
    this.items = Channels.find({'title':'/' + valueToSearch + '/'});
}
```

I tried /valueToSearch/ too, but it doesn't return any result.

Comment: So maybe I misunderstood your question, as I couldn't understand why you were embedding slashes. Are you trying to do a full text search / regex?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To construct a regular expression from string you can use `RegExp`

```
searchChannel(valueToSearch:string){
    this.items = Channels.find({'title': new RegExp(valueToSearch)});
}
```

Comment: Wow - so I didn't even pick up on the OP's need to do a regex search. Completely missed that in the description.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, work like a charm !
@David : I wasn't clear enough I got to admit ! My bad thanks you for your answer tho :)

Answer (score 0):

Ok so... the issue is likely because you're inserting `/` characters into your mongo query. I think you want something like this:

```
searchChannel(valueToSearch:string){
    this.items = Channels.find({'title': valueToSearch });
}
```

Unless the `/` characters are part of your stored content, they shouldn't be added to your search string.